# How to create a dropdown list depending on the userlevel logged-in in phpmaker?

Tags: php

How do I create a dropdown list depending on the userlevel currently logged-in using PHPMAKER?

So far I've only created a Dynamic Selection List https://phpmaker.dev/doc/dynamicselect.htm which I must manually select the User Level dropdown in order to call the data linked to Remarks. But I want it to automatically set the data in user level depending on the user currently logged-in and also call the data related to user level selection in remarks.

For example if I am logged-in and I belong to CFRR userlevel, then the drop down I must see in Remarks must Database, Referrals, and Others Only.

here are my tables:

Table: **remarks_data**
Columns:
remarks_data_id int(11) AI PK
Userlevel int(11)
Remarks int(11)

Table: **remarks**
Columns:
remarks_id int(11) AI PK
Userlevel int(11)
Remarks varchar(45)

Table: **userlevels**
Columns:
userlevelid int(11) PK
userlevelname varchar(80)

Table: **users**
Columns:
user_id int(10) AI PK
userlevel_id int(10)
username varchar(45)
password varchar(45)
firstname varchar(45)
lastname varchar(45)

[here is the screenshot of the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kwi7.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, I have already updated my question, I hope you can help me with this. Thanks